# not able to validate keyword using regular expression validators

Tags: c#, asp.net

All ..I want to parse text from user in format of H1,H,H1TUT
BUT not able to do using following Expression [A-Z][0-9][T][U][T]|[A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9]|[A-Z]
What could be fault?? 
it allows all expect length 0f 2 string like..
It allows H1TUT,H but not allowing H1...........

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator0"  ForeColor="#6600FF" 
                        runat="server" ErrorMessage="Batch Name Should be like H,H1,H1TUT" 
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbbatchname" ValidationGroup="form"
                            ValidationExpression="[A-Z][0-9][T][U][T]|[A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9]|[A-Z]">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex pattern:

```
([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[T][U][T])|([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([A-Z]{1})
```

Maybe you can avoid using the {1} parts I just added them to be safe.

Edit: The point here is you start by looking for your longest pattern to the shorter, you can see I added `|` character to denote the `Or` logic.

Regards,